# Laradock - Can't read mariadb data folder

Tags: laravel, mariadb, laradock

I have build a laravel app with Laradock. I've some issue with mariadb container. This is the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
mariadb:
      build:
        context: ./mariadb
        args:
          - http_proxy
          - https_proxy
          - no_proxy
          - MARIADB_VERSION=${MARIADB_VERSION}
      volumes:
        - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
        - ${MARIADB_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      environment:
        - TZ=${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MARIADB_DATABASE}
        - MYSQL_USER=${MARIADB_USER}
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MARIADB_PASSWORD}
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      networks:
        - backend
      restart: always
```

`${DATA_PATH_HOST}` is `~/laradock/data`.

I can read the database with phpmyadmin, with a lot of data. After a `docker-compose down` or `docker-compose stop`, the database is empty but the folder `~/laradock/data/mariadb` and (inside container) `/var/lib/mysql` have this file:

```
total 121M
-rw-rw---- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump  32K Dec  2 13:10 aria_log.00000001
-rw-rw---- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump   52 Dec  2 13:10 aria_log_control
-rw-rw---- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump  976 Dec  2 13:10 ib_buffer_pool
-rw-rw---- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump  12M Dec  2 13:10 ibdata1
-rw-rw---- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump  96M Dec  2 13:10 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw---- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump  12M Dec  2 13:10 ibtmp1
-rw-rw---- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump    0 Dec  2 12:32 multi-master.info
drwx------ 2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 4.0K Dec  2 12:32 mysql
drwx------ 2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 4.0K Dec  2 12:32 performance_schema
drwx------ 2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 4.0K Dec  2 12:32 myuserdb
```

It seems the data is persisted on disk, but is inaccessible via cli o phpmyadmin. No errors in log.
How I can restore data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note: To use with MariaDB, open .env and set
`PMA_DB_ENGINE=mysql to PMA_DB_ENGINE=mariadb`.

Then, try

```
docker-compose up -d mariadb phpmyadmin
```

https://laradock.io/documentation/#use-phpmyadmin

Comment: Already done. The data is inaccessible also via cli, inside mariadb container. Thanks.